# What are Transformations? and What are their properties?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, transformation

I am an engineer, so maybe this question is naive.

In my view, transformation is a kind of map that transforms space points into new ones. To preserve space structure, this map must be a function, injective, and subjective. Some examples are translate, rotate, etc. Also, I see Fourier transform, Laplace transform, etc. in this category.

Transformers are my interest. Therefore, I started to study about them. I spent some time in Topology (I can't find any difference between algebraic Topology and general Topology), Differential geometry, and Functional analysis. After that, I was a little confused. I think none of them can't completely answer my questions.

**What am I trying to find about transformers?**

Characteristics of transformers,
applications of them,
affective spaces,
structure of new space,
can we design them,
can transform affect just on a structure from space not on whole,
etc.

**Example of what I have in mind**

Consider a 2-dimensional curve with an equation:

$\ f(x)= ax^3 + bx^2 + cx +d$

And assume a transform exists such that it changes this curve to a logarithmic curve, or any polynomial curve, or 3-dimensional surface, etc.

**What is my question?**

which part of math describes the transformer and its behavior?

From where is it better to study about them?

Can you name some good sources?

Comment: If you want to receive a good answer you will have to be more specific about the kinds of transformations you are considering. Also, are you using transformers and transformations as synonyms?

Comment: @VincentBoelens do you refer to linear or non-linear as a transformation kind? In my view, transformers are maps that do the action of transformation.

Comment: I am not referring to anything. You say you are interested in transformations, but this is simply too broad of a category to say anything meaningful about it. You have to be more specific. Different fields of mathematics are interested in different kinds of transformations.

Comment: @VincentBoelens I think you mean the application of transformation to for example PDE. I want to apply it to curves or surfaces or even higher dimensional functions to change them to a simple form (for example, polynomials in 2-dimensional).

Comment: This still very broad if you do not clearly state what kind of output your transformation should have as well as the expected relationship between input and output. Curves and surfaces are usually studied in differential and algebraic geometry. Have you looked at textbooks?

Comment: Maybe Category theory? It seems a little more general than what you describe, but the basic concept is describing mathematical theories by the "morphisms" of the theory - which are usually maps that preserve the properties that define the theory. For example, in topology, morphisms are the continuous maps. In linear algebra, morphisms are linear maps between vector spaces. etc. Morphisms do not have to be maps between sets, but most examples are.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Nope but thank you it seems you answered Another one of my questions.